# UIPicker specific question(iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipicker

I am starting to learn to use the UIPicker in an application.  what I want to do is that when the user clicks on the zipcode textbox, I want the uipicker to pop up and display list of zipcodes available.  Just like a drop down in c# or VB.net.  Do I have to create a new view and place the uipicker there?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a UIPickerView appearing in your app you do not need an additional view.

Assuming you are in a UIViewController:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {
    UIPickerView* mPicker;
}
-(void)showPicker;
-(void)hidePicker;
@end

-(void)showPicker {
    [self.view addSubview:mPicker];
    mPicker.center = CGPoint // set out of sight

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    // do your transformations
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)hidePicker {
    // do your exit animations
}
```

You can also add a delegate function to the second animations to remove the mPicker from the superview.

For more information have a look at the [UIView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a view for placing a text box. It does not matter if it needs to be a new view or the old view - just place the text box in the view you require.
2. make sure that

   ```
   textField.inputView = yourPickerView;
   ```

Comment: +1 You might also need to add an `inputAccessoryView` to dismiss the picker.